# SQL - Calculate the difference between rows using another column to indicate changes

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table like this and I want to calculate the difference between FrameNum when TeamId is the same. I need to treat the TeamId column as a switch. As soon as TeamId changes, I need to calculate the difference between the StartFrameNum and EndFrameNum. There's a case where you may only have a single TeamId(row 12), so I think I'll need to grab the next FrameNum then subtract the starting FrameNum. I'm open to different ways of doing this if it makes sense.

| FrameNum | TeamId |
| --- | --- |
| 8398 | 1 |
| 8420 | 1 |
| 8452 | 1 |
| 8478 | 2 |
| 8494 | 2 |
| 8511 | 1 |
| 8545 | 1 |
| 8563 | 2 |
| 8604 | 2 |
| 8641 | 2 |
| 8698 | 2 |
| 8708 | 1 |
| 8741 | 2 |
| 8772 | 2 |

My desired output looks like this.

| StartFrameNum | EndFrameNum | Duration | TeamId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8398 | 8478 | 80 | 1 |
| 8478 | 8511 | 33 | 2 |
| 8511 | 8563 | 52 | 1 |
| 8563 | 8708 | 145 | 2 |
| 8708 | 8741 | 33 | 1 |
| 8741 | 8772 | 33 | 2 |

This is the query I've started writing. It's not correct. I don't know if I'm going in the right direction. Any help or advice would be appreciated. I'm using SQL Server. Thanks in advance.

```
WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT 
        TeamId, FrameNum, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY RN1 - RN2 ORDER BY FrameNum) RN3, 
        RN1
    FROM 
        (SELECT 
             TeamId, FrameNum,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY FrameNum) RN1,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TeamId ORDER BY FrameNum) RN2
         FROM 
             Table) T
)
SELECT 
    C1.TeamId, C1.FrameNum,
    C1.FrameNum - X.FrameNum [IndividualDifference]
FROM
    CTE C1
OUTER APPLY 
    (SELECT MAX(FrameNum)
     FROM CTE
     WHERE RN3 = 1
       AND RN1 < C1.RN1) X(FrameNum)
WHERE 
    C1.RN3 = 1  
ORDER BY 
    C1.FrameNum;
```

Comment: How about using LAG to look if TeamId changed since prev row, and if it did put 1, else put 0, then SUM OVER ORDERBY framenum that to get a column that only increments when the teamid changes, then you can get min and max by grouping that sometimes-incrementing counter

Answer (score 1):

You don't need aggregation for this, just window functions:

```
select teamid, framenum as start_framenum,
       lead(framenum, 1, last_framenum) over (order by framenum) as end_framenum,
       (lead(framenum, 1, last_framenum) over (order by framenum) - framenum) as duration
from (select t.*,
             lag(teamid) over (order by framenum) as prev_teamid,
             max(framenum) over () as last_framenum
      from t
     ) t
where prev_teamid is null or pre_teamid <> teamid;
```

The idea is to keep the first row for each team when the team changes.  Then after filtering use `lead()` to get the next `framenum`, because you want the result to perfectly tile.

You need the maximum `framenum` just for the last row.

Answer (score 1):

**This is a type of *gaps-and-islands* problem, for which there are a number of solutions.**

Here is one:

- We start by using `LAG` to define the island starting point
- We use `COUNT OVER` to create a group ID
- We group by that and pull out the aggregated info we need from each group

```sql
WITH StartPoints AS (
    SELECT *,
      CASE WHEN LAG(TeamId) OVER (ORDER BY FrameNum) = TeamId THEN NULL ELSE 1 END IsStart
    FROM YourTable t
),
Groupings AS (
    SELECT *,
      COUNT(IsStart) OVER (ORDER BY FrameNum ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) GroupId
    FROM StartPoints
)
SELECT
  MIN(FrameNum) AS StartFrameNum,
  LEAD(MIN(FrameNum), 1, MAX(FrameNum)) OVER (ORDER BY GroupId) EndFrameNum,
  LEAD(MIN(FrameNum), 1, MAX(FrameNum)) OVER (ORDER BY GroupId) - MIN(FrameNum) Duration,
  MIN(TeamId) TeamId
FROM Groupings
GROUP BY GroupId
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ab816710174c50b8a31d70cffbd87ac0)